# How to write a trigger in sqlite to delete rows after 1 day?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to write an sqlite trigger query to delete rows when its created time reached one day old.

Is it possible to delete rows automatically after 1 day without user intervention. Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Triggers are executed only when some specific changes happens. But why do you care what's in the database as long as you aren't looking at it? Can't your program automatically execute something every day?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers need some change to execute the task.
For Trigger demo [Trigger Demo](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-sqlite-trigger-demo.html)

You can try this option:

1. You can create a local timer to track the time.And accordingly update the value in db.

   Now as the update is performed your trigger will be fired & gonna delete the row.

e.g:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER if not exists delete_row   
       AFTER UPDATE   
     ON[first]  
      for each row  
        BEGIN  
            delete from second name where sid = old.sid;  
        END;
```

Here trigger deletes the row from second when update is performed on the first.

Hope this could give you some idea.